# Child theme required for WordPress wp-bootstrap-navwalker?

Tags: wordpress

I have a bootstrap WordPress theme which I am happy with, except for the navigation.

Do you recommend that I create the navigation within a child theme?

The navigation is based upon the WP Bootstrap Navwalker.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I recommend using the WordPress Navigation with Bootstrap's Styles in your Child theme. it's a little tricky, but a great skill to have, it will come in handy once you figure it out!

Comment: thanks - can you point me to any tutorials or advice that helped you out?